# VB.net INSERT statement not able to store data in database but got no exception?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am trying to store data in the sql database using vb.net. In my code I am using parameters to add values..
Below is my code:

```vb
Dim lclAmount = txtQty.Text * txtUnitPrice.Text
con = New SqlConnection(connectionString)
' con.Open()

query = "INSERT INTO TBLExpensesList (ExpensesType, Purpose, Qty, UnitPrice, Amount, DoP, Description) VALUES (@val1, @val2, @val3, @val4, @val5, @val6, @val7)"

cmd = New SqlCommand(query, con)

cmd.Parameters.Add(cmd.CreateParameter).ParameterName = "@val1"
cmd.Parameters.Add(cmd.CreateParameter).ParameterName = "@val2"
cmd.Parameters.Add(cmd.CreateParameter).ParameterName = "@val3"
cmd.Parameters.Add(cmd.CreateParameter).ParameterName = "@val4"
cmd.Parameters.Add(cmd.CreateParameter).ParameterName = "@val5"
cmd.Parameters.Add(cmd.CreateParameter).ParameterName = "@val6"
cmd.Parameters.Add(cmd.CreateParameter).ParameterName = "@val7"


cmd.Parameters("@val1").Value = ComboBox1.SelectedItem
cmd.Parameters("@val2").Value = txtPurpose.Text
cmd.Parameters("@val3").Value = txtQty.Text
cmd.Parameters("@val4").Value = txtUnitPrice.Text
cmd.Parameters("@val5").Value = lclAmount
cmd.Parameters("@val6").Value = dtpDOP.Value
cmd.Parameters("@val7").Value = txtDesc.Text



If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
     con.Open()
End If
' cmd.CommandText = query
'                cmd.Connection = con
'Create Data Adaptor
'                sqladp.SelectCommand = cmd
'Create & Fill Data Set
'sqladp.Fill(ds, "TBLExpensesList")
'Get Data Table
'dtbl = ds.Tables("TBLExpensesList")

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

If con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
    con.Close()
End If

MessageBox.Show("Data Inserted Successfully!", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.None)


'Execute Command


Catch ex As Exception
      MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
End Try

End If
```

I am successfully able to login into my project when the useid and passwords matches the stored values in the database. But when i try to store values I got Inserted successfully and after that When I try to read the rows I got one row.
When I close my project ad try to see the values it the database I got no value in the database..
I am also confusing that why the values are not being stored in the database????

Comment: If you work from a database file sometimes in debug mode it regenerates the file and hence the changes are only on the go. Try to compile into the release and run the exe from the folder directly.

Comment: hi, already in release mode

Comment: Are you debugging in release mode?

Comment: i have tried in debug and release mode both but I got the same issue.

Comment: If you read my message I asked you go to the release folder and directly launch the Exe not to debug

Comment: Hi, yes Data is there if i execute from release mode... But this is not way to work with VS2013???

Comment: As I explained when you debug the file regenerates every time specially if you changed the data structure while coding.

Comment: Partly agree, how the usertables information is not affected. As, login id and password are also stored there

Comment: please take time to write a proper sentence before posting as it is hard to understand what you are saying

Comment: hi, i apologize, I am having N tables in the database and I hard coded the values in 2 tables like user info and when I login, I am able to login. it means the value is in the database.
I m facing this issue when I try to run INSERT statement. DO you have any appropriate solution for this?

Comment: What error do you have when doing insert.

Comment: As, I have already mentioned that I am not getting any error but I need that the data should be persist each and every time. because I need it for other forms also. and no one wants to execute the .exe from release to check either the data is there or not

Comment: Add this code `Dim rowsAffected As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` and advise what `rowsAffected` is when you run the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read up on [Working with local databases](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/smartclientdata/2005/08/26/working-with-local-databases/). A quote from there (emphasis mine):

> At design-time, MyProject\Data.mdf is used by the data tools. At run-time, the app will be using the database under the output folder. **As a result of the copy, many people have the impression that the app did not save the data to the database file.** In fact, this is simply because there are two copies of the data file involved. Same applies when looking at the schema/data through the database explorer. The tools are using the copy in the project, not the one in the bin folder.

Comment: hi, i agree with you. but  no one wants to execute the .exe from release to check either the data is there or not.